# Loading and showing the xml file and its content in Apache cordova?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am using Apache cordova api for developing mobile application. I want to load the xml file and show the contents of xml file in a page of mobile app. Anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../your xml url here/",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml){    

            $(xml).find('a').each(function(){
                $.each(this.attributes, function(b, attr){
                     var name = attr.name;
                     var value = attr.value;
                    // do your operation here.
                });
             });        

        }, 
        error: function(model, xhr, options) { 
            alert("error");
        }
    });
```